# what is the difference between these two export statements on JAVA_HOME?

Tags: macos, maven, export, environment-variables

I set up my `JAVA_HOME` using `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home` as recommend by `Apple`. but it failed. This [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/maven-java_home-is-not-defined-correctly-on-mac-osx/) referred to use `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` and that worked.

so what is the difference between these two?

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java_home is a tool that is intended to help determine the correct value for the JAVA_HOME environment variable. From the man-page (`man java_home`):

```
  The java_home command returns a path suitable for setting the JAVA_HOME
  environment variable. It determines this path from the user's enabled and
  preferred JVMs in the Java Preferences application. Additional constraints
  may be provided to filter the list of JVMs available. By default, if no
  constraints match the available list of JVMs, the default order is used.
  The path is printed to standard output.
```

Now, in bash, surrounding a command with `$( ... )` inserts the standard output printed by the enclosed command. So, your export statement:

```
        export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

... means "set JAVA_HOME to the value printed by running `/usr/libexec/java_home`."

Without the surrounding $(...), the export just sets the JAVA_HOME variable to the literal string "/usr/libexec/java_home", which is certainly not what you want.

Comment: and how is that different from `JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home`